# How to use a sidenav under a toolbar

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I am trying to use the toolbar component and the sidenav but, if I use it in the following way, only the toolbar of my component disappears:

```
<!--Toolbar of sidebar-->
<app-toolbar></app-toolbar> 
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container">
   <mat-sidenav opened mode="side">   
   </mat-sidenav>
   <!--Toolbar of sidebar-->
   <app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
 </mat-sidenav-container>
```

But if I use it in the following way, the toolbar is inside the content of the sidenav; how can I do so that the toolbar is on top of the dashboard-type sidenav (I know how to hide it or show it according to an event, but due to limitations, the best option is to keep it in sight)?

```
 <mat-sidenav-container class="example-container">
   <mat-sidenav opened mode="side">   
   </mat-sidenav>
   <!--Toolbar of sidebar-->
   <app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
 </mat-sidenav-container>
```

**Example (Expected)**

[image: Image dashboard]

Comment: Maybe you could use a `<mat-sidenav-content>` tag inside `<mat-sidenav-container>` tag and place `<app-toolbar>` and the rest of the content inside it